# Helm managing a collection of services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster that runs a number of independent, discrete services. I want to use helm to deploy them, and I have made a helm chart for every individual resource.

However, now I want to be able to deploy the cluster as a single entity, but it is not clear to me how helm supports stitching together multiple charts.

When I look at example repos, they simply have every single template file in the template folder of a single chart, and then a giant, sprawling Values.yaml file.

To me, that seems unwieldly, especially crawling around a 2000 line Values.yaml looking for settings.

Is there any way to take a folder structure that looks like this:

```
helm
|____ Service1
      |_______ values.yaml
      |_______ templates
      Service2
      |_______ values.yaml
      |_______ templates
      Service3
      |_______ values.yaml
      |_______ templates
```

And package it into one deployment without manually merging and de-duping the files and values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [helm subcharts](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)

You'd need to have something like a meta-chart, `myapps`. Then you'd add a `requirements.yaml` file like so:

```
# myapp/requirements.yaml
dependencies:
  - name: Service1
    repository: http://localhost:10191
    version: 0.1.0
  - name: Service2
    repository: http://localhost:10191
    version: 0.1.0
  - name: Service3
    repository: http://localhost:10191
    version: 0.1.0
```

Answer (score 5):

We also have similar scenarios wherein we have independent applications that we either need to deploy together to address features that span across them or individually deployed to address bugs.
We end up using helmfile (https://github.com/roboll/helmfile).
Each application still maintain their own charts, using helmfile, we can deploy them altogether if need to.

Comment: Helmfile is awesome! Can't recommend it enough. We have a full write up on using `helmfile` in our documentation: https://docs.cloudposse.com/tools/helmfile/