# Hierarchy of values for dynamic helm chart configuration

Tags: kubernetes-helm

### What I'm trying to do

I want to have some default settings and options in `values.yaml`, and then a hash map of different instances, which will be converted into services and deployments, whose individual settings override the defaults.

#### `values.yaml`

```
someSetting: TheDefault
deployments:
  one:
    role: XYZ
  two:
    role: ABC
    someSetting: Overridden
```

In the above case, there would be two deployments and services, `one` and `two`.  The value for `someSetting` for `one` would be `TheDefault` and for `two` would be `Overridden`.

#### `actual template yaml`

I'm trying this - to build a dictionary, `$p`, which has the root-scope `Chart` and `Release` objects in it, then has the root scope values merged in, then the current deployment value merged in.

```
{{- range $deploymentKey, $deploymentVal := .Values.deployments }}
{{- $p := dict "deploymentKey" $deploymentKey }}
{{- $_ := set $p "Chart" $.Chart }}
{{- $_ := set $p "Release" $.Release }}
{{- $_ := merge $p $.Values }}
{{- $_ := merge $p . }}
...
{{- end }}
```

The reason for including `Chart` and `Release` is that, despite what the documentation says, `$.Chart` is not always available - it's literally empty when I pass a scope into a template and that template tries to use `$.` to refer to root scope.

So I'm doing things like:

`name: {{ template "my-app.fullname" $p }}`

and

`image: {{ $p.image.name }}`

## The error

The problem is that while `helm lint` returns no errors, `helm template .` (or a dry-run) yields:

`Error: rendering template failed: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

### What I've tried

- Removing each `merge` to try to narrow down the crash - they don't seem to cause it
- Plain-old merging `$` into the dictionary
- Weeping
- Asking on Helm Slack
- Asking on GitHub issues

### My question..

How can I fix this crash?

Or, how can I achieve what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

deployment.yaml:

```
{{- range $deploymentKey, $deploymentVal := .Values.deployments }}
{{- $p := dict "deploymentKey" $deploymentKey }}
{{- $_ := set $p "Chart" $.Chart }}
{{- $_ := set $p "Release" $.Release }}
{{- $_ := merge $p . }}
{{- $_ := merge $p $.Values }}
...
{{ end }}
```

_helpers.tpl:

```
{{- define "repro.fullname" -}}
{{- printf "%s" .Chart.Name }}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes swapping the two merge lines was an important part of it :)  The crash bug I had was to do with the `merge` statements - when my `Values.yaml` had a blank key (in my case, `env:` with no sub-keys/values) - will be raising a GH issue around that.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead create a common base chart with the defaults and a vanilla service and deployment and then create an umbrella chart that includes the base chart twice under the aliases 'one' and 'two'. Then the values file of the umbrella chart is where you override the defaults and you don't need any dictionary.

As an example here is a base chart - https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/configmaps-transformers/tree/master/helm/transformers/charts/transformer and the umbrella chart includes it multiple times under different aliases - https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/configmaps-transformers/blob/master/helm/transformers/requirements.yaml. The umbrella chart's values file plugs in different values for each instance of the base chart that is included. In the umbrella values each instance is referenced by its alias - https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/configmaps-transformers/blob/master/helm/transformers/values.yaml#L14

Comment: thanks, would that work dynamically? Im looking to have values.yaml (ie the user of the final chart) specify how many services / deployments there are?

Comment: I see now, a chart that was dynamic like that would be very interesting. I would first approach it as concrete as possible, so without the dictionary first. Initially I'd try to loop through the deployments (one, two etc.) with a range function. Might make it a list of easier but hopefully map. So there would be a deployments.yaml that is wrapped in a loop function like range and with separators between the generated deployments and each with unique name from the keys. Then try to add the defaulting in when that is working. Could use the default function, being careful with scoping from loop.

Comment: Would be good to chat about this - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186257/room-for-ryan-dawson-and-kieren-johnstone

Comment: I have the range working, just need the defaulting, but would like to use a dictionary rather than checking/defaulting each and every value.  Merging `$.Values` and `.` within a range into a dictionary causes the helm process to crash

Comment: Yeah I guess there will be a lot of repetition with 'default' or 'if exists else'

Comment: Might be that living with the repetition is best option for now

Comment: I've raised https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5131 re the best way to do this kind of dynamic chart. I'm thinking another issue is going to be needed for the merge within a range problem.

Comment: Have added https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/dynamicchart as an illustration based on yours but without dictionary

Comment: @KierenJohnstone might also be worth looking at the tools discussed in  https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/79wlj1/helmfile_a_declarative_spec_for_deploying_helm/ - especially helmfile - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51547967/9705485